# Redirect from exception filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core. One of my controllers calls into services which throw various exceptions. I want to handle them in an exception filter (not middleware).

```
public class MyHandlerAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext c)
    {
      if (c.Exception is FooException) {
          // redirect with arguments to here
      } 
      else if (c.Exception is FooException) {
          // redirect with arguments to there
      }
      else {
          // redirect to main error action without arguments, as 500
      }
      base.OnException(c);
    }
}
```

Unlike action filters, an exception filter doesn't give me access to the `Controller`, so I can't do a `c.Result = controller.RedirectTo...()`.

So how do I redirect to my error action?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `HttpContext` is exposed on the `ExceptionContext`, so you can use it for the redirection.

```
context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("...");
```

There is also a `Result` property, but I don't know if it'll be interpreted after the execution of the filter. It's worth a try though:

```
context.Result = new RedirectResult("...");
```

If it works, it should also work with `RedirectToActionResult` or `RedirectToRouteResult`.

Comment: The second one doesn't work. The first one works if you also set `context.Exception = null;` However this type of redirect doesn't let me specify arguments - is that possible?

Comment: The second option works also. But you should also set `context.ExceptionHandled = true;`.

Comment: @juunas If I do that, then it just renders a blank page... Weird!

Comment: In summary: the first form works but one cannot pass arguments, the second form accepts arguments but doesn't work due to a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to a controller's action AND also pass one or more values you need to use a `RouteValueDictionary`. This works for redirecting and passing data from an `ExceptionFilterAttribute` to a controller method.

In the following example I am redirecting to error controller's Test_Error action and pass an integer value (id). This is tested using .NET Core 2.2

**The Custom Attribute**

```
public class Custom_ExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    var routeData = new RouteValueDictionary(new {
                      controller = "Error",
                      action = "Test_Error",
                      id = 1,
                   });
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeData);
    filterContext.Result.ExecuteResultAsync(filterContext);
}
```

**The controller with action**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
     public IActionResult Test_Error(int id)
     {
         //do whatever
     }
}
```

Of course you can pass the exception, the controller and the action where the exception was thrown to the controller's action and handle it from there.